# How to calculate wavelet energy-to-Shannon entropy ratio to select best mother discrete wavelet in python?

Tags: python, wavelet

I'm doing a wavelet analysis to sensor data, however, I realise that there are a lot of wavelet families to select from. I have read an article that says: "The method firstly uses a criterion of maximum energy-to-Shannon entropy ratio to select the appropriate wavelet base for signal analysis.". So, I would like to know how to calculate the energy-to-Shannon entropy ratio of a sensor signal in python?

Comment: Can you give us some sample data, as well as some things you tried? Also, a formula of energy-to-Shannon entropy could help

Comment: @Nakor Well, my input data is an acceleration data collected from the accelerometer sensor connected to a wooden bridge. So, I am using the data collected in order to monitor the structural condition of the bridge. The data can be found from the following website: http://users.metropolia.fi/~kullj/JrkwXyZGkhF/

Comment: @Nakor I managed to get some values (from the code below), so, what I did is that I get the coefficients of the wavelet and use that to get the ratio value of each sensor. then I combine the ratios into a list in order to calculate the average of the Energy-to-Shannon entropy ratio of relevant wavelet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess assuming the text meant : np.max(Total Energy/Total Entropy)|wavelet

```
import pywt
import numpy as np

#series - input data
#wave   - current wavelet
data=pywt.wavedec(series,wave)
S=0
Etot=0
for d in data:
    E=d**2
    P=E/np.sum(E)
    S+=-np.sum(P*np.log(P))
    Etot+=np.sum(E)
ratio=Etot/S
```

Then repeated for each candidate wavelet

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try and implement your code, but, I have a question. Say, for example, I found a mother wavelet but it has multiple versions like 'db 1', 'db5',  'db7', etc.. How can I find the suitable version say for my program?

Comment: Ultimately that is a fitness-for-purpose question, and in a lot of applications most wavelets will have comparable performance.  Without knowing more about your source data or your end goals, it's hard to say what further refinements you might want to do.
Keep in mind that the 'db38' will take longer to compute than a 'db4', so if the end use will be done in multiple calculations there is a processing constraint to be wary of on top of quality.  
There are certain cross-validation techniques, but I've never had to use them myself.

Comment: Well, my input data is an acceleration data collected from the accelerometer sensor connected to a wooden bridge. So, I am using the data collected to monitor the structural condition of the bridge. The data can be found from the following website: http://users.metropolia.fi/~kullj/JrkwXyZGkhF/

Comment: I managed to get some values so what I did is that I get the coefficients of the wavelet and use that to get the ratio value of each sensor. then I combine the ratios into a list in order to calculate the average of the Energy-to-Shannon entropy ratio of relevant wavelet.

Answer (score 1):

I think NRG's code have a confusion.

```
import pywt
import numpy as np
#series - input data
#wave   - current wavelet
data=pywt.wavedec(series,wave)
S=0
Etot=0
for d in data:
    E=d**2
    Etot+=np.sum(E)
    P=E/Etot
    S+=-np.sum(P*np.log(P))
ratio=Etot/S
```

That is Etot and np.sum(E)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

While NRG's code is representative, I believe the calculation of entropy above is wrong, as we need to first discretize the distribution of the wavelet coefficients before computing the entropy. Here's a slightly modified version (based on their code) that illustrates this:

```py
import pywt
import numpy as np

#series - input data
#wave   - current wavelet
data = pywt.wavedec(series,wave)
S = 0
Etot = 0
for d in data:
    E = d**2
    P = E / np.sum(E) #the normalization is not strictly necessary...
    P_counts, _ = np.histogram(P, bins='auto') #discretize the distribution of coefficients
    P_counts = P_counts / sum(P_counts) #converts the counts into probabilities
    S += -np.sum(P_counts * np.log(P_counts)) #compute the entropy
    Etot += np.sum(E)
ratio = Etot/S
```